# Need help for Diploma thesis: calculating preferred direction of gradient vector

Tags: fortran90

i am currently writing my Diploma thesis in Fortran 90. At a certain stage of my code, i simply want to calculate an Integer (should give a direction in a cartesian grid of mesh cells as a result).

There are no error messages, but the result is wrong. What can it be? The value i am looking for is that of the variable `idirhf` (see below). it should always be either `1`, `2`, or `3`. Depending on the calculated `preferred` direction. However, it is often `idirhf = 0` or maybe even `idirhf = 1195` or whatever...the values `fcdx`, `fcdy` and `fcdz` are `Real` values. they represant the components of a gradient.

All variables are declared in a previous step which is not shown.

Can anybody help? i have already spent hours on that little issue now...

Here is a part of the code:

```
              distz = ( dr ( k ) +  dr ( k - 1 ) + dr ( k + 1) ) / 2.

              fcdx = ( fv  ( i + 1, j, k ) - fv  ( i - 1, j ,k ) )      &
     &                / ( 2. * dz )
              fcdy = ( fv  ( i, j + 1, k ) - fv  ( i, j - 1, k ) )      &
     &                / ( 2. * dp )
              fcdz = ( fv  ( i, j, k + 1 ) - fv  ( i, j ,k - 1 ) )      &
     &                / ( distz )
              gradf ( 1 ) = ABS ( fcdx )
              gradf ( 2 ) = ABS ( fcdy )
              gradf ( 3 ) = ABS ( fcdz )
!
!             Prüfung in welche der 3 Kooridnatenrichtung x,y,z
!             die HF gebildet werden soll:
!
              IF ( gradf(1) > gradf(2) ) THEN
                 IF ( gradf(1) > gradf(3) ) THEN
                    idirhf = x
                    x = 1
                    ider1 = y
                    ider2 = z
                    nsten1 = 5
                    nsten2 = 5
                 END IF
              END IF
!
              IF ( gradf(2) > gradf(1) ) THEN
                 IF ( gradf(2) > gradf(3) ) THEN
                   idirhf = y
                    y = 2
                    ider1 = x
                    ider2 = z
                    nsten1 = 4
                    nsten2 = 5
                 END IF
              END IF
!
              IF ( gradf(3) > gradf(1) ) THEN
                 IF ( gradf(3) > gradf(2) ) THEN
                    idirhf = z
                    z = 3
                    ider1 = x
                    ider2 = y
                    nsten1 = 4
                    nsten2 = 5
                 END IF
              END IF
!              WRITE(*,*)'###Nach gradf-Vergleich.idirhf = ', idirhf
```

Comment: I think Mark is correct and you have misplaced the assignment to `idirhf` and `x`, `y`, or `z`. Besides Fortran has the logical `.AND.` operator - no need to use nested `IF`s.

Comment: in fact, just to make the logic clearer, I'd be tempted to rewrite this as `integer :: maxdir; maxdir = maxloc(gradf); select case (maxdir)  case(1)...`   Note too that as it stands currently, if (say) `gradf(1)==gradf(2) > gradf(3)`, none of the if bodies will get executed; exact numerical equality might be unlikely but not at all impossible (say, for example, if some derivitives are zero in the initial conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post doesn't show us the values of `x,y,z` before they are first used to update `idirhf` inside your double `IF` statements.  Should the sequence

```
                idirhf = x
                x = 1
```

really be

```
                x = 1
                idirhf = x
```

*etc* ?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply and the helpful answers. I will change my source. I already tried idirhf=MAXLOC(gradf) command. However i didnt choose the select case command so it didn't run, although i declared gradf as an allocated field with 1 column and 3 components.

Comment: I now have it like you told Mark. its still the same. And thanks for your advice Hristo Illiev. I already used .AND. & .OR. commands in addtition with the operators >=, <= to choose one direction even if two of three values are numerically equal. My supervisor didnt want that do to the fact that it might be too complicated for other persons who deal with the code.